# Table with text wrapping and two "=" aligned equations in one cell

Tags: tables

Regarding this post:

[Table with text wrapping?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54069/table-with-text-wrapping)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|L|c|L|}\hline
one & two & three \\\hline
This is two line thing and centered & only one line&  \multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{This is justified and may go to second line as well, neatly}\\\hline
  one & two & three \\\hline
  one & two & three \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to enhance this table as follows:

1. Turn the  Row 2, Column1 text into two equations aligned at the "=" within that cell. That is:

   > y=mx+b
   >   y=x+1
2. Insert caption and label
3. Position the table and caption in the center of the page

Answer (score 5):

Check out the following modified form of your MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{The table's caption goes here}\label{tab:example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|L|c|L|}\hline
one & two & three \\
\hline
This is two line thing and centered & only one line&  
\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{This is justified and may go to second line as well, neatly}\\
\hline
  $\begin{aligned}
  y&=mx+b\\
  y&=x+1
  \end{aligned}$ & two & three \\\hline
  one & two & three \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I've made the following changes to your code to address your objectives:

- Row 2, Column 1, contains an `aligned` environment (inside the `$` ... `$` math mode delimiters), with the `&` symbol used to align the equations on the respective equal signs.
- There are new `\caption` and `\label` commands between `\begin{table}` and `\begin{tabular}`
- There's a `\centering` directive immediately before the `\begin{tabular}` statement. Note that the caption will be centered automatically (unless it's longer than `\textwidth`).