# Longtable dimensions not appearing

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, align, wrap, tabulary

I have the following packages loaded:

```
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false} % optional
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} % "decimal" column type
\renewcommand{\ast}{{}^{\textstyle *}} % for raised "asterisks"
```

And within my document have:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{longtable}{|L|c|L|}\hline
\textbf{Example Sentence} & \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Explanation}
\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{3cm}|}{We send the EU £350m a week}
 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{3cm}|}{Use a real number, but change its meaning to be in the wrong context
}&  \multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{This is a true National Statistic but it “is not an amount of money that the UK pays to the EU”. In fact, the UK’s net contribution is more like £250m a week which equates to £136m. }
\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{3cm}|}{Potential cost of leaving the EU as £4,300 per household per year, rather than as the equivalent £120bn for the whole country}
 & \multicolumn{1}{|m{3cm}|}{Make the number look big (but not too big)}&  \multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Insert text}
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{table}
```

Altered from [this source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54069/table-with-text-wrapping).

I have a few issues:

[image: First two rows of table]

1. At the moment, everything is centre aligned and so the text contains too much spacing instead of being left aligned and tight
2. I want to make the whole table wrap to its contents. At the moment I limit everything on a per column basis to 3cm but actually I want to limit the whole table to be at max the width of my page (if that is a variable somewhere?) and autowrap.
3. My table doesn't spill over the page as I thought `longtable` would do. If I remove the `table` wrapping in the longtable I cannot specify `[!ht]` so my table would appear on some random part of the page.

How do I solve this?

Comment: as others have said you should never put longtable in a table. But also `[!ht]` isn't usually a good option to use for tables, it prevents the float being put on a float or bottom of a page (as no `b` or `p`) so makes it far more likely that the float can not be placed and drifts to the end of the document, and `!` means that  the typographic constraints set by the document class are ignored, which presumably typically makes worse output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine your claims:

> At the moment, everything is centre aligned and so the text contains too much spacing instead of being left aligned and tight

This claim is incorrect. You do specify the `L` column type (which you've defined to center-set its contents), but then you override this setting via `\multicolumn{1}{|m{3cm}|}{...}` wrappers. The `m` column type fully justifies its contents. What one sees in your screenshot is not centered text but fully justified text with large "holes" between lots of words.

To get ragged-right formatting, either use

```
\multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|}{...}
```

wrappers or remove the wrappers entirely and replace `\centering` with `\raggedright` in the definition of the `L` column type.

> ...I want to limit the whole table to be at max the width of my page (if that is a variable somewhere?) and autowrap

Have you looked into the [ltxtable](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) environment? Use it in conjunction with `longtable` environments.

> My table doesn't spill over the page as I thought longtable would do. If I remove the table wrapping in the longtable I cannot specify [!ht] so my table would appear on some random part of the page.

The premise that `longtable` is a floating environment is *false*. It is not. The reason why `[ht!]` has no effect when applied to a `longtable` is that a `longtable` always starts right where it's encountered in the input stream. Thus: *Never* encase a `longtable` inside a `table`. Never, ever. No way, no how.

---

Here's how I would re-work your code. Note that I've re-organized the material inside the `longtable` to distinguish more clearly between header, footer, and body of the table. I've also gotten rid of all vertical lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.75cm}}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}LLL@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Example Sentence} & \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Explanation}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
We send the EU £350m a week & 
Use a real number, but change its meaning to be in the wrong context&  
This is a true National Statistic but it ``is not an amount of money that the UK pays to the EU''. In fact, the UK's net contribution is more like £250m a week which equates to £136m.\\
\midrule
Potential cost of leaving the EU as £4,300 per household per year, rather than as the equivalent £120bn for the whole country & 
Make the number look big (but not too big)&  
Insert text\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I make it so the third column is slightly wider than the others as it is likely to be the longest?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - Let's assume you still want the sum of the three column widths to be 11.25cm. First, change the definition of the `L` column type to take a parameter: `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`. Second, start the `longtable` as follows, say: `\begin{longtable}{@{}L{3.5cm}L{3.5cm}L{4.25cm}@{}}`.

Comment: Hi @Mico, this may benefit other readers, but I added `\caption{The caption of the table}
\label{table:somename}` just above `\toprule` but am now getting a compilation error. I want a caption to appear on top of the table.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - Did you place a double backslash (line break directive) after`\caption`?

Comment: ```\begin{longtable}{@{}L{3.5cm}L{3.5cm}L{4.25cm}@{}}
\caption{The caption of the table}
\label{table:somename}
\toprule
\textbf{Example Sentence} & \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Explanation}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
We send the EU £350m a week & 
Use a real number, but change its meaning to be in the wrong context&  
This is a true National Statistic but it ``is not an amount of money that the UK pays to the EU''. In fact, the UK's net contribution is more like £250m a week which equates to £136m.\\```

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - So, indeed, your code is missing a line-break directive after `\caption` and `\label` (and before `\toprule`).

Answer (score 0):

A `longtable` is *not* a float, so you must not use the `table` environment.

I propose two solutions, based on `ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable`  to `tabularx`.  One solution use vertical and horizontal lines, the other uses the rules from `booktabs`, without vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{geometry}%
 \usepackage{array,ltablex, makecell}%
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{ragged2e} \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false} % optional
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} % "decimal" column type
\renewcommand{\ast}{{}^{\textstyle *}} % for raised "asterisks"

\usepackage{showframe} \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}

\begin{document}


\centering\keepXColumns
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{3}{ >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}}%
\hline %
 \thead{Example Sentence} & \thead{Category} & \thead{Explanation} \\%
\hline
We send the EU £\,350\,m a week
 & Use a real number, but change its meaning to be in the wrong context
& This is a true National Statistic but it “is not an amount of money that the UK pays to the EU”. In fact, the UK’s net contribution is more like £\,250\,m a week which equates to £\,136\,m. \\%
\hline
Potential cost of leaving the EU as £\,4,300 per household per year, rather than as the equivalent £\,120\,bn for the whole country & Make the number look big (but not too big) & Insert text \\%
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
\vskip1cm

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{ >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}}%
\toprule %
 \thead{Example Sentence} & \thead{Category} & \thead{Explanation} \\%
\midrule
We send the EU £\,350\,m a week
 & Use a real number, but change its meaning to be in the wrong context
& This is a true National Statistic but it “is not an amount of money that the UK pays to the EU”. In fact, the UK’s net contribution is more like £\,250\,m a week which equates to £\,136\,m. \\%
\addlinespace
Potential cost of leaving the EU as £\,4,300 per household per year, rather than as the equivalent £\,120\,bn for the whole country & Make the number look big (but not too big) & Insert text \\%
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]