# Runaway argument error for tabulary

Tags: tables, multicolumn, wrap, tabulary

I am using tabulary and have set up my environment like so:

```
\usepackage{array,ltablex, makecell}%
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newenvironment{conditions}
 {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
 {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}%This is for descriptions of equations
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}% This is for quotes
\usepackage{tabulary}% This is for tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable,array}% This is formatting for long tables
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

And then, when I want to make a table with wrapped text, taken from this example, I get:

```
Runaway argument?
>{\raggedright \arraybackslash }p{L}\relax \NC@do D\NC@do d\NC@do V\@iwhilesw \
ETC.
Paragraph ended before \NC@find was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.96   \end{tabulary}
```

Using this code I got from this link (to get wrapped text):

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabulary}{0.7\textwidth}{LCL}
    Short sentences      & \#  & Long sentences                                                 \\
    \hline
    This is short.       & 173 & This is much loooooooonger, because there are many more words.  \\
    This is not shorter. & 317 & This is still loooooooonger, because there are many more words. \\
  \end{tabulary}  
\end{center}
```

My overarching goal is to produce a table which looks like:

[image]

But which is now looking like:

https://cl.ly/1e2h2J3y3k2i

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I guess it's because you define `\newcolumntype{L}[1]` with one argument, but do not supply an argument in the table column specification `{LCL}` (according from what I see from the `array` documentation, `\newcolumntype` does not support arguments).

Comment: Also, `tabulary` already defines a column of type `L`. I guess you should not redefine it, or use another letter (at least for consistency).

Comment: According to your definition, `L` requires an argument. But it's completely wrong to redefine that column type, which is needed by `tabulary`

Comment: `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` will break tabulary completely, what is the intention of that definition?

Comment: The definition of the new column type was from this question I asked separately - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325873/longtable-dimensions-not-appearing. I don't want to be tied to that same format, the longtable format, is there a way of me just specifying the above setting for my `longtables` and thus not overriding the standard tabular environment?

Answer (score 1):

You define the `L` column type to take an argument, viz.,

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

yet you then employ it as not taking an argument:

```
\begin{tabulary}{0.7\textwidth}{LCL}
```

The error about the runaway argument arises because LaTeX is -- unsucessfully -- looking for the argument of `L`. Moreover, the `L` column type has already been defined by the `tabulary` environment.

I think you should (a) use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabulary` environment and (b) strike the argument from the definition of the `L` column type. I.e., something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{LcL}
    Short sentences      & \#  & Long sentences\\
    \hline
    This is short.       & 173 & This is much loooooooonger, because there are many more words.  \\
    This is not shorter. & 317 & This is still loooooooonger, because there are many more words. \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If your ultimate objective is to use a `longtable` environment, you shouldn't be loading the `tabulary` package either. Instead, I suggest you proceed along the lines of the following example code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{L{0.25\textwidth}cL{0.25\textwidth}}
    Short sentences      & \#  & Long sentences\\
    \hline
    \endhead
    This is short.       & 173 & This is much loooooooonger, because there are many more words.  \\
    This is not shorter. & 317 & This is still loooooooonger, because there are many more words. \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I read that the `longtable` environment is only helpful for tables that span many pages. In that sense, it seems like the most versatile option (because it doesn't necessarily span multiple pages, only when needed?). In which case the addendum solution you posted would be best?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - A `longtable` environment *can* span two or more pages, but it does not have to. If the table does fit on a single page and if, for some reason, you want it to be placed all on one page, then by all means do *not* use a `longtable` environment; instead, use a `tabular` (or `tabularx`, or `tabulary`, or whatever) environment, possibly encased in a `table` environment. Conversely, if you don't mind a page break, do look into using a `longtable`.

Comment: Seems like I have to choose between them as setting parameters for fixed columns for one (`longtable`) would mean overriding the natural parameters for `tabular`, so I'll go with `longtable`.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - I must confess I don't know what you mean by "the natural parameters" of a `tabular` environment. What's unnatural about a raggedright version of the `p` column type?

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|}\hline\hline
Features&Example\\\hline\hline
Here & There\\\hline
Today&Tomorrow\\\hline
Good & Bad \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|} {I need to add full two columns}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I have added a  tabular example to generate the table you needed.