# Wrapping text in tables which contains underscores

Tags: tables, tabularx, verbatim, wrap, tabulary

I have lots of text in multiple columns in tables which contains items with underscores. However, these do not wrap around a fixed column width, so I get:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{report}
 \usepackage{array,ltablex, makecell}%
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
% \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}%This is for descriptions to appear on the LHS with an indent
\newenvironment{conditions}
 {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
 {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}%This is for descriptions of equations
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}% This is for quotes
\usepackage{tabulary}% This is for tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}% This is formatting for long tables
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}% This is for images
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}%This is for precision tables per property
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} % "decimal" column type
\renewcommand{\ast}{{}^{\textstyle *}} % for raised "asterisks"


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{List of Open and Closed Evaluation Properties}
\label{table:openclosed}
\ra{1.0}%This stretches the contents of cells
\begin{tabular}{|C{4cm}|C{4cm}|C{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Open Properties} & \textbf{Closed Properties} & 
\textbf{Sentence Label Properties} \\ 
\hline 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\verb|gni_per_capita_in_ppp_dollars|\\
\verb|health_expenditure_as_percent_of_gdp|\\ 
\end{tabular}                   
& 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\verb|gni_in_ppp_dollars|\\
\verb|gni_per_capita_in_ppp_dollars|\\
\verb|health_expenditure_as_percent_of_gdp|\\
\verb|internet_users_percent_population|\\
\verb|labor_participation_rate|\\
\verb|life_expectancy|\\
\verb|merchandise_trade_percent_of_gdp|\\
\verb|net_migration|\\
\verb|population|\\
\verb|population_growth_rate|\\
\verb|prevalence_of_undernourisment|\\
\verb|renewable_freshwater_per_capita|\\
\verb|size_of_armed_forces|\\  
\end{tabular}
& 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\verb|consumer_price_index|\\
\verb|cpi_inflation_rate|\\
\verb|diesel_price_liter|\\ 
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I get these values to wrap around and fit the cells in new lines if they go beyond the allocated width? In addition, if any column contains less rows than the longest column in its row (e.g. column 2 has less items than column 1), I would like the text to start at the top instead of the middle. Just adding `[t]` to the inner tabulars didn't seem to work per this: [Top alignment of cell content in tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103601/top-alignment-of-cell-content-in-tabularx).

Answer (score 3):

Your code, as written, provides three separate reasons for why line breaks aren't occurring inside the long "words":

- line breaks aren't allowed inside verbatim-type groups
- line breaks aren't allowed inside columns of type `l`
- LaTeX simply doesn't know where to insert line breaks in these long "words". And even if LaTeX did know, it would insert hyphen characters, which is probably rather undesirable.

You haven't indicated *where* inside the long words line breaks are permissible; in what follows, I assume line breaks are permitted only after `_` (underscore) characters.

The following example applies the following modifications to your code:

- A `tabularx` environment is used for the tabular material.
- All `\verb` directives are removed; they are replaced with `\ttfamily` directives in the definition of the `L` column type. That way, the material will still be typeset using a monospaced font, but long words will be wrapped *if* a suitable line break can be found.
- Most importantly, the underscore characters are made "active" -- in the TeX sense of the word -- and are given the meaning `\textunderscore\hspace{0pt}`. The redefinition of `_` is done inside the `table` environment; hence, the redefinition expires when `\end{table}` is encountered. That way, line breaks without hyphen characters are made possible after each and every underscore character.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
% preamble stripped down to the bare minimum
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,caption}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\ttfamily\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
\catcode`_=13 % Make _ "active"; 
%% This setting expires at end of current group, i.e., at end of "table" environment
\def_{\textunderscore\hspace{0pt}} % "meaning" of "_"

\caption{List of Open and Closed Evaluation Properties}
\label{table:openclosed}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|}
\hline
\textbf{Open Properties} &  \textbf{Closed Properties} & \textbf{Sentence Label Properties} \\
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}L@{}}
gni_per_capita_in_ppp_dollars\\
health_expenditure_as_percent_of_gdp\\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{@{}L@{}}
gni_in_ppp_dollars\\
gni_per_capita_in_ppp_dollars\\
health_expenditure_as_percent_of_gdp\\
internet_users_percent_population\\
labor_participation_rate\\
life_expectancy\\
merchandise_trade_percent_of_gdp\\
net_migration\\
population\\
population_growth_rate\\
prevalence_of_undernourisment\\
renewable_freshwater_per_capita\\
size_of_armed_forces\\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{@{}L@{}}
consumer_price_index\\
cpi_inflation_rate\\
diesel_price_liter\\
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico, how would I adapt to each column is top aligned (text starts from top of cell)?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - Change all three instances of `\begin{tabular}{@{}L@{}}` to `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}L@{}}`. (I had assumed, apparently incorrectly, that you wanted centered alignment instead of top alignment of the columns since the code you posted uses `m`-type rather than `p`-type columns...)

Comment: I would love to use this but it removes the fixed column spacing I needed for another table in my document, which is a longtable, created via - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325873/longtable-dimensions-not-appearing. By resetting this, and also loading tabulary, it messes things up. Is there a way of doing this using the same `L` and `C` setup as before?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - I really wish you had mentioned at the outset that you need to enable page breaks of the `longtable` variety. (For sure, the use of a `table` environment in the code you posted didn't indicate in any way that you would need to allow page breaks. Ditto for  the`tabulary` environment -- it also doesn't allow page breaks.) I'm afraid that allowing pagebreaks is going to require a completely different setup. Shall I just delete this answer? It definitely appears to be of little or no value to you, doesn't it. Please advise.

Comment: I'll revise the question so is clearer. I have tried to have a work around of having multiple commands e.g. allowing `\begin{longtable}{@{}LL{4cm}LL{4cm}LL{6cm}@{}}` for my long tables but also `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|}`

Comment: Actually let me redo this, will post question.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - You should post a *new question* rather than revise the existing question "so [it] is clearer". For sure, if you heavily modify the original question, the answer I've posted will be of no value whatsoever and should therefore be deleted -- and will be deleted.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327798/allowing-for-multiple-column-types-with-longtable-to-allow-page-break-and-norm

Comment: I will delete this question then.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - Sure, go ahead.

Comment: did you manage to take a look? I guess the complexity is that I want the ability to have both types of tables - one that span pages and ones that dont.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44871/discussion-between-dhruv-ghulati-and-mico).