# table long text

Tags: tables, text

I want to create a column in a table that will be a long text.

I have tried this

```
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.65}

    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{*{7}{l}}

    \toprule[1.2pt]
    Variable & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Description} \\ 
    \cmidrule[0.8pt](lr){1-7}
        loan amnt & asfasfaf Descriptive statistics for some of the variables & \\
        int rate & \\
        credit grade &  \\


    \midrule[1.2pt]
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Dictionary of the variables}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
```

[image]

I know that it  must be smth super simple but I'm new to this.

Any suggestion?

Comment: you have declared the table has 7 columns with no linebreaking  `*{7}{l}` you only have 2 columns so `lp{4cm}`  or whatever width you need for the second column

Comment: Please see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54069/85946).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle where should I add this `lp{4cm}` ?

Comment: instead of *{7}l which is specifying 7 columns, also if you only have two columns `\multicolumn{6}{c}{Description}` should be `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description}`

Comment: no if you use `p{4cm}` the column with the long text will be 4cm wide, make it 2cm if you want it narrower.  If something is wrong fix your example so that it can be run so people can see the output, examples should be complete small documents.

Comment: why have you specified 7 columns everywhet `*{7}{l} and `\makecolumn{6}` and `\cmidrule[0.8pt](lr){1-7}`  you only have two columns

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, that worked for me . is any way to set the space between the line of the text?

Comment: all spaces can be set but I can not guess what you mean (perhaps you shoudl ask a new question with a real example)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't know how to set the length of the table thats why. Also the other tables have 7 variables so I wanted the length to be the same as the others.