# set space between text lines in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to set the space between the text of the following variables so it can look nice.

```
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.65}

    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{lp{12cm}{l}}

    \toprule[1.2pt]
    \textbf{Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Description}} \\ 
    \cmidrule[0.8pt](lr){1-2}
    loan amnt & Asfasfaf Descriptive statistics for some of the                  Dictionary of the variables variables \\
    int rate & Interest rate of the loans Dictionary of the variables variables \\
    credit grade & based on its fico score Dictionary of the variables variables \\


    \midrule[1.2pt]
    \end{tabular}

     \begin{tablenotes}[online, flushleft]
   \tiny
   \item[]Notes: Dictionary for most of the variables is taken from the dictionary file
 \end{tablenotes}

    \caption{Dictionary of the variables}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
```

what I'm getting is

[image]

any suggestion?

Comment: Please see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54069/85946).

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Why do you specify 3 columns, if you only want to use 2? And why do you use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.65}`?

Comment: @samcarter if you see the table above "variables variables" is very close to the description for the int rate. I want it to be close to the 1st line and have some spaces between the explanation of each variable

Comment: @leandriis I'm new to this, so I do not know what each command is doing. I was taking a ready format from somewhere

Comment: _again_ you have not provided an example. the spacing you show with more space between lines in a cell than between the table rows is weird and due to code you have not shown.  You should always post an example that produces the image that you post.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the image above is what I'm getting when I run the code that I have posted

Comment: No the code you have posted will produce no output,  you should post a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` as in the answer that is posted below. the spacing you show is due to settings you have not shown, also you use constructs not defined by default such as `H` and `tablenotes` so you make people guess how to define those to run your example at all.

Comment: that said the main thing wrong is `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.65}` which you should delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would redesign your table in:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

- please always provide complete but small document as you can see in my answer it below
- to answer on your question is far more easy, if we know relevant part of your real document preamble (packages related to your problem and to page layout)
- in showed solution i assume that your table can has width equal to `\textwidth` and for table environment use `tabularx` environment. its column type `X` automatically calculate column width.
- for rules in table i suggest to use default thickness for rules. in the package `booktabs` are deliberately selected ...
- for notes below table i would use `threeparttablex` with option `referable`, which define command `\note`.
- `online` is not defined in `threeparttable` (as far as i know), instead it i use option `para`
- suggest you to read some basic about table settings with `latex`. for start for example [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} % <--- for \note, \source in threepartable

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Dictionary of the variables}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
    \toprule
 \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Description}   \\
    \midrule
oan amnt        & Asfasfaf Descriptive statistics for some of the Dictionary of the variables variables \\
int rate        & Interest rate of the loans Dictionary of the variables variables \\
credit grade    & based on its fico score Dictionary of the variables variables \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
    \scriptsize
\note: Dictionary for most of the variables is taken from the dictionary file
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Small suggestion: the code could be further simplified by removing `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` around `\textbf{Description}`

Comment: ups, i forgot on this. corrected. thank you very much, @samcarter!