# Prevent table from going out of the page

Tags: tables

Hi I am having an issue when trying to create tables that are twofold:

(1) The contents of the second columns keep going out of the page even when I try to create line breaks. (Preferably I would like to avoid using line breaks and would prefer if Texmaker would automatically create a new line instead of going out of the page).

(2) The contents of the second columns do not always start from the left of the box.

I only have two columns and it is the second column with the descriptions (i.e. blah blah) that are causing the problems.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
\hline
\textbf{Architecture} & \textbf{Limitations}                                                                                                               \\ \hline

Header1  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \\ blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \\ blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \\ blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah\\blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{tabular}\\ \hline

Header2& 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\ \\ \\ 
\end{tabular}\\ \hline
Header3& 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Header4& 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You can see some other answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54069/table-with-text-wrapping) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790932/how-to-wrap-text-in-latex-tables).  The first uses the `array` package, while the second simply uses the `p{}` column definition to do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suppose, that you looking for the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
\textbf{Architecture} & \textbf{Limitations}        \\
                \hline
Header1  & blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
            \\  \hline

Header2 &   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
            \\ \hline
Header3 &   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
            \\ \hline
Header4 &   blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
            \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- use`center` environment ad additional vertical space around `tabular`. for its centering on `table` float environment is better to use command `\centering` (see mwe below).
- you nested `tabular` with column type  `c`, which not automatic break lines when table reach desired width. apparently your manual breaking of text content is not adequate, so you have to long text rows that they can be placed on page
- suggested use of `tabularx` enable to automatic calculation of width of the second column and breaking a text in it.

Comment: Thanks! This worked - unfortunately I can not +1 this as I don't have enough points for that privilege yet.

Comment: @Mellow, you will do when you earn enough reputation :-). welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Thanks for your help again :-)

Comment: I have just given you a '+1' now as I met the reputation threshold :)

Comment: congratulation for cross a threshold! happy texting!